# Bundle not found after changing ruby version with RVM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, bundler

I feel like this is a super beginner question with an obvious answer but I'm missing it.

I'm installing a Rails project that includes a gem requiring me to use a version of Ruby that is 2.2.2 or earlier. Since my current system is set up with a newer version of Ruby, when I run `bundle install`, it fails because one of the gems can't be installed with the newest version of Ruby.

So, I set my system to use ruby 2.2.2 with rvm, `rvm use ruby-2.2.2`.

I then run `bundle install` and get `zsh: command not found: bundle`. Why is this? All my other commands work and I can install the problem gem individually with `gem install`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You probably had Bundler installed for the version of ruby you've been using until this point.  However, Bundler is not installed on versions of ruby provided by RVM by default, so for after you switch to ruby-2.2.2, install Bundler for that ruby:

```
gem install bundler
```

Then try running `bundle install` again.

Answer (score 4):

If you just switched to a new version of ruby on your RVM install 2.2.2 in this case the

```
  gem install bundler
```

command listed as correct above is only going to solve this error for that single gemset. I would suggest running the following command to avoid it for any other gemsets also tied to the same version of ruby.

```
  rvm use 2.2.2@global
  gem install bundler
```

That will put the *bundler* gem into your *global* 2.2.2 gemset making it available but over writable by all other 2.2.2 gemsets.  You can also install gems like nokogiri and such that are common but very time consuming into this global 2.2 gemset

Comment: Michael Deering's suggestion was especially helpful to me, and my bundler was pointing at my system Ruby rather than my RVM install of Ruby, despite that I had set the latter as my default. Putting the bundler gem into a global gemset for my RVM Ruby install got things working.